# How to highlight text using macros and visual basic in LibreOffice

Tags: macros, libreoffice

I have to write a macro that highlights specific numbers (to set the background color to yellow).

I have already written a macro that finds these numbers using object Cursor but i don't know how to change the background color.

```
Dim Cursor As Object
Dim Proceed As Boolean

Cursor = ThisComponent.Text.createTextCursor()
Cursor.gotoStart(False)

Do
    Cursor.gotoEndOfWord(True)

    'some If statements that check if the number is correct
        'Cursor.CharEmphasis = com.sun.star.text.FontEmphasis.DOT_BELOW
    Proceed = Cursor.gotoNextWord(False)        
Loop While Proceed
```

I found a function that emphasises the text with dots below the text. Is there something similar for highlighting the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [CharBackColor](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/style/CharacterProperties.html#CharBackColor):

```
oCursor.CharBackColor = RGB(255,255,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will put yellow background at any cell with entry less than MY_MIN or more than MY_MAX in the cell range from col1 to col2 and row1 to row2.

```
For I = col1 To col2
 For J = row1 to row2
    Cell = Sheet.getCellByPosition(I,J)
    If Cell.Type <> com.sun.star.table.CellContentType.EMPTY Then
        If Cell.Value < MY_MIN Or Cell.Value > MY_MAX Then
            Cell.CellBackColor = RGB(200,200,0)
        End If
    End If
 Next J
Next I
```

Hope, this solves your problem.